# Most performant SQL query needed

Tags: sql-server

I'm storing documents with fields that are set in a DataSource table. The document is written to the database as follows:

Document table (ID, DataSourceID)
Document fields (DocumentID, DataSourceField, FieldValue)

For example:

```
Document
100 | "Invoice"
101 | "Receipt"

Fields
100 | "Date" | 2011/12/01
100 | "Amount" | 1200,00
101 | "Date" | 2011/12/02
101 | "Warehouse" | "Central"
```

The documents have many more fields. Now, the question is how to write the fastest query to find documents by entering some filter values on fields (ie. Date between '2011/12/1' and '2011/12/31' and Amount > 1000,00)?

This is what I came up:

```
select * from Document, Fields 
where DocumentID = FieldDocumentID and DataSource = "Invoice"
and DocumentID in (select FieldDocumentID from Fields where Field = "Date"
and FieldValue between '2011/12/01' and '2011/12/31')
and DocumentID in (select FieldDocumentID from Fields where Field = "Amount"
and FieldValue >= 1000)
```

I'm not sure how well this is going to work with millions of rows. How could I do this better?

Comment: The best idea is not to use this structure, since there's no way to enforce data types and you will have all sorts of implicit conversions.  EAV is an antipattern for a reason.

Comment: joins would probably make it run faster than using subselects, and also don't use *.

Comment: How about more conventional database structure - table with fields DocumentID, Date, Amount and so on? Or is this out of question?

Comment: Instead of trying to get an SQL-query optimized for you DB you should do some performance tests with dummy data. Analyze what the RDBM is doing with the query and try to optimize in whatever way possible, by tweaking. Optimization is something that can be dependent on so many factors and if you really want to write fast queries, you should start by being able to profile. When you've got your profiles, come back and ask why a certain scenario runs faster than another one, and I'm sure you'll get some interesting answers. Just don't forget to explain what your circumstances are (what DBMS you're

Comment: The users will define fields for documents. This structure is the only way to do this AFAIK.

Comment: @Nezreli: If you want your users to be defining fields - and also want a normalized database - look for **6NF**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_normal_form

Comment: I have no time to write a proper answer now. But your query seems pretty fine (for the EAV structure you have). You could rewrite it using `EXISTS` or `JOIN` with (I guess) pretty much the same performance.

Comment: it is all well and good to allow the user to define their own fields, however you will never get any good performance out of this sort of system.  Your best bet is to do a compromise and have a parent table contain all of the foreseeable fields, including your DocumentID and Date, etc.  You can then create some proper indexes and find all the relvelant DocumnetIDs.  From there you can do the joins to get all the miscellaneous attributes.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no common fields except DocumentID. The system will be used by medical, military, financial and tourism companies. It's quite the challenge.

Comment: Note that you do a **text** comparison on the dates, but as long as it's in a yyyy/mm/dd format it should work out ok.

Comment: @HansKesting is right. The checks will work for dates (and strings) but probably not for numeric data. I would expect the SQL to evaluate `'1200.00' < '800.00'` as true!

Comment: Redesign is your first and best choice, consider using a nosql database which is at least more optimized for this type of task. Or do proper design work and create tables withthe columns you will need. You may need different tables for each business sector but if they have similar fields in each sector, then that will be light years faster than EAV.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EAV based systems (e.g. Agresso) have query performance problems inherent to the EAV structure.  The problems are really based on three underlying issues:

- The structure is fiddly to query, so you get added complexity in your queries.
- You can't index the base table on any of the attributes, which drives some inherent inefficiency in the query plans.
- You have to do multiple joins against a large table.

Some possible strategies for mitigating EAV performance problems are:

- Using a clustered index to keep all records relating to a given parent in close physical proximity can help somewhat.  This minimises the I/O.
- Consider using the metadata to create a view that flattens out the EAV structure.  You may have to redefine the view every time it changes, and it won't necessarily help performance much, but it will be much easier to query.  Try to create the view as a roll-up rather than a multiple way join.
- Any attribute that is not strictly user defined (eg. transaction dates, amounts) should go on the base table.  These can also be indexed.
- Resolve the most selective predicates in subqueries first and join against the sub-query.
- If you have the option flatten out the physical structure, even if it has to be into a series of fields like 'StringField1', 'StringField2', 'DateField1', 'MoneyField1'.  Your application will have to hold the configration data anyway, so you can just map to a field on the database.
  This sounds clumsy, but it's much more efficient to query, and it doesn't have to be in the users' faces.  You can also use the metadata to generate a view over the table that names the fields, so other customers of the data can see a meaningful view of the data and query it without necessarily having access to the application metadata. 
  If you run out of columns in the table, just add more in the database.  The field mapping system can always query the system data dictionary to see what's available.

At some point in these debates, somebody often chips in with a comment about XML columns ("I know, I'll just use XML").  To paraphrase JWZ, now you have two problems.  Around 1998 they installed another circle in hell just for people who defile their systems with XML blob fields.

Although it doesn't look slick and high-tech, just having a set of user attribute columns on the table is by far the best solution.  It is the most efficient, and there are many ways to make this approach more user friendly at the database level.

**EDIT:** Here is a snippet of T-SQL showing how to create a view that flattens out an EAV structure.  Note that you wound have to write a generator for the view based on the application's attribute metadata and re-create it every time this is changed.

```
if object_id ('dbo.Foo') is not null
    drop table dbo.Foo
go

if object_id ('dbo.FooView') is not null
    drop view dbo.FooView
go 

create table dbo.Foo (
       FooID     int not null
      ,FooKey    varchar (20)
      ,FooVal    varchar (100)
)

insert Foo (FooID, FooKey, FooVal)
values (1, 'Date', '2011-11-11')

insert Foo (FooID, FooKey, FooVal)
values (1, 'Amount', '100')

insert Foo (FooID, FooKey, FooVal)
values (2, 'Date', '2012-12-12')

insert Foo (FooID, FooKey, FooVal)
values (2, 'Amount', '200')
go

create view dbo.FooView
    as
select *
  from (select FooID
              ,FooKey
              ,FooVal
          from dbo.Foo) keys
 pivot (Max (FooVal) 
        for FooKey in ([Date],[Amount])) pvt
go

select * from dbo.FooView
```

This is much more efficient than solutions involving multiple self-joins on the table, and will be somewhat efficient with a clustered index on the base entity and attribute type keys.  You will probably also want to put type conversions into the view so you can sort the results correctly.

Comment: This is an `OR` query, not an `AND`. Why do you think a `PIVOT` would be more efficient than a self-join?

Comment: It's an example of flattening out an EAV structure for reporting purposes.  A view of this sort would be more efficient on aggregate queries where it would be just one table scan instead of a large multi-way self-join - i.e. better for reporting.

Comment: Why do you think that one table scan over all values is better than two independent scans on appropriate portions of the index? If we have 1M documents with 20 attributes in each, your solution would need to scan 20M records while even op's one would only need to scan 2M.

Comment: Depends how selective the query is.  If you're just selecting a few rows then what you're talking about in your post will probably be more efficnent.  However, I think it would end up with some sort of intermediate bookmarking operation.  More than a few percent of rows overall and a single table scan would be cheaper.  When I tested it the plan was just a table scan, then aggregation and filtering the aggregate.

Comment: A properly designed `EAV` table (well, let's say a least improperly designed table since we're talking `EAV`) should be clustered on `fieldName` leading, so there is no row lookup overhead here. With a clustered seek, even `99%` percent of rows would be cheaper than `100%`.

Comment: @Quassnoi - Clustering like that would give you faster searches but scatter the data for single parent record over the table.  I suppose you could complement that with a covering index organised the other way around (parent, attribute).

Comment: nice point too.

Comment: @Quassnoi - I suppose it's worth mentioning that I'm thinking more from a reporting perspective as I mostly work on data warehouse systems these days.  In that racket a table scan is par for the course, at least if you can get the I/O tuned on the server so it will do sequential reads at a decent speed.  Anything involving random seeks will usually be much slower than a table scan for anything that selects more than a few percent of the rows in the table.

Comment: Awesome post and a great discussion. For reporting I'm creating a subsystem that is able to create a classic table from my data source and populate it from the EAV table. After that only slowdown will be for inserts and updates which is acceptable to me. Changing the datasource itself will cause rebuilding of that table. The solution needs to work on several different databases which is another challenge.

Answer (score 2):

Create computed numeric and date fields in your EAV table and indexes on them:

```
ALTER TABLE fields ADD FieldValueNumeric AS CASE ISNUMERIC(FieldValue) WHEN 1 THEN CAST(FieldValue AS NUMERIC) END

ALTER TABLE fields ADD FieldValueDate AS CASE ISDATE(FieldValue) WHEN 1 THEN CAST(FieldValue AS DATE) END

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_fields_field_num_doc ON fields (dataSourceField, fieldValueNumeric, documentId)

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_fields_field_date_doc ON fields (dataSourceField, fieldValueDate, documentId)
```

and use them in your query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    document
WHERE   documentID IN
        (
        SELECT  fieldDocumentID
        FROM    fields
        WHERE   dataSourceField = 'Date'
                AND fieldValueDate BETWEEN '2011/12/01' AND '2011/12/31'
        )
        AND documentID IN
        (
        SELECT  fieldDocumentID
        FROM    fields
        WHERE   dataSourceField = 'Amount'
                AND fieldValueNumeric >= 1000
        )
```

EAV has its drawbacks, but for this very query (with ranged conditions on two dirrefent attributes) it's no worse than if the attributes were in one table, since a single index on two fields would be useless for ranged scans on both (in `SQL Server`).

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of creating several columns in my table (one for int, nvarchar, char, varbinary, bool and datetime). Still not sure if I'm going to create indexes on them.

Comment: @Nezreli: you can just keep the datatype in a separate column and use the computed columns like this: `valueDate AS CASE DATATYPE WHEN 'D' THEN CAST(value AS DATE) END` etc. There is no point in persisting the columns. Of course you should index them if you want faster ranged searches.

Comment: I already have a datatype column. Not sure if all databases support creation of such computed fields (Informix and PostgreSQL ie.) hence my decision for more conservative approach. But, I'll look into it since it's more elegant solution.

Comment: @Nezreli: Not sure about `Informix`, but `Oracle` and `PostgreSQL` allow indexing expressions: `CREATE INDEX ON (name, CASE datatype WHEN 'D' THEN CAST(value AS DATE) END, id)`. You should use the expression verbatim in you query for this index to work. `MySQL` does not support this (as well as creating computed columns, persisted or not, at all).

Comment: Ok, wikipedia says that Informix supports indexing expressions. Thanks, I'll go with computed columns.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I would go with something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Document d
INNER JOIN Fields f ON f.FieldDocumentID = d.DocumentID
WHERE d.DataSource = 'Invoice'
AND ( (f.Field = 'Date' AND FieldValue BETWEEN '2011/12/01' AND '2011/12/31')
   OR (f.Field = 'Amount' AND FieldValue >= 1000)
   OR ...
   );
```

It's always a good idea to spell-out your JOINs instead of specifying multiple tables in the FROM clause.  This helps prevent unexpected results, and protects you from doing an unintended Cartesian JOIN (if you make a mistake in your WHERE clause).

Comment: In what way would this help performance?

Comment: This will not even work. No row can have `f.field` equal to both `'Date'` and `'Amount'`

Comment: I don't thinks this is a correct SQL query. This one will return just Date and Amount rows. I need all document fileds for those documents which satisfy my filter criteria.

Comment: @JNK- I've eliminated two subqueries...the performance benefit should be obvious.  With the mish-mash of datatypes in the Fields table (and assuming a database redesign isn't going to happen) I think this should do a fair job of reaching the goal here.

Comment: @ypercube- If you look, the f.Field checks in the WHERE clause are in different parts of an "OR".

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 - those subqueries were short-circuiting `IN` clauses so they performed pretty well already.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23: My mistake, you are right. It's not totally wrong, just doesn't return what the OP asks for.